# Align Fbox to the left and text to the right

Tags: alignment, fbox

I m a beginner with LaTex and I don't really understand how to align an FBox to the left with an image inside and some text to the right.

**Current implementation without boxing:**

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width = 0.5\linewidth]{graph_southampton.PNG}
\end{minipage}

\hfill

\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}\raggedleft

Yesasd asdjkasdk jakdsajkd\\
alsdjaojzxkc \\
asdjkasm

\end{minipage}
```

**Output:**

[image]

As you may notice they are not properly aligned, I just sent you a bit from what I have before and after to get a glimpse of my page format.

**Now with Boxing**

```
\noindent\fbox{ 

    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
        \lefting
        \includegraphics[width = 0.5\linewidth]{graph_southampton.PNG}
    \end{minipage}

    \hfill

    \begin{minipage}{0.001\textwidth}

        asdaksdaskdl

    \end{minipage}

}
```

**Output**

[image]

The box size is perfect but the text outruns the boundaries.

Could you please help me with some suggestions on both cases?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the `\lefting` command?

Comment: @Bernard Oh..Don't mind that, I was just playing around thinking that ```\lefting``` is the same as ```begin{left}``` -> ```end{left}```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an empty line starts a new paragraph

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tiger}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}\raggedleft     
        Yesasd asdjkasdk jakdsajkd\\
        alsdjaojzxkc \\
        asdjkasm
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For an image with a caption use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\begin{document}

\hvFloat[capPos=right,capVPos=bottom,objectFrame]{figure}%
   {\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{tiger}}%
   {The caption of the figure which is on the right bottom
    of the page.}%
   {fig-label}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked fine but why mine didn't?

Comment: If I want to add a caption to the image, should I use ```begin{figure}``` instead of just ```\includegraphics```

Comment: As I already wrote: An empty line starts a new paragraph, so your `\hfill` is useless. See edited answer for a caption.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the simplest possible code, with the `valign` key from `adjustbox` (and no blank lines):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}
\usepackage{caption} 


\begin{document}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.\bigskip

\noindent\fbox{\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{\includegraphics[width =\linewidth, valign=c]{LaDormeuse}\captionof{figure}{Toyen, La Dormeuse (1937)}}} \hfill asdaksdaskdl


 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And how would you put caption, I mean inside the FBox.

Comment: ```\noindent\fbox{\includegraphics[width = 0.5\linewidth, valign=c]{graph_southampton.PNG}}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.40\textwidth}\centering    
        The picture on the left represents \\
        a \textcolor{blue}{graph}. The \textcolor{blue}{source} point is \\
        corresponds to Southampton whereas \\ 
        the \textcolor{blue}{destinations} are the other cities. \newline
        The edges are also labeled with the shortest path between the cities.
\end{minipage}``` For this code I get a big white space above my text.

Comment: For men the minipage is vertically centred w.r.t. the image.  For the caption, I'll post a solution in a moment.

Comment: What do you suggest me to do in order to get rid of that big white space ? Is it because of that ```valign=c```. Thank you!

Comment: Try `valign=t`for include graphics and also write `\begin{minipage[t]{0.40\textwidth}`. But maybe it is due to a blank upper part in your graphic file.

Comment: No it does not work, anyway I ll see. Thank you though.