# Align image and text horizontally

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, minipage

I am trying to align an image and text horizontally on a page.

This is an extra question for what I have asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490465/align-fbox-to-the-left-and-text-to-the-right). I got some suggestions in comments: like add `[t]` to the minipage, but it does not seem to work.

Thanks in advance!

**My code:**

```
\noindent\fbox{\includegraphics[width = 0.5\linewidth, valign=c]{graph_southampton.PNG}}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.40\textwidth}\centering    
        The picture on the left represents \\
        a \textcolor{blue}{graph}. The \textcolor{blue}{source} point is \\
        corresponds to Southampton whereas \\ 
        the \textcolor{blue}{destinations} are the other cities. \newline
        The edges are also labeled with the shortest path between the cities.
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

Comment: showed result has not been generated with showed code (why you use it from Bernard answer, which you not accept?). it gives  perfect result. so your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just that alignment you do not need anything special. (I am not sure though if I would go for this layout, but that's your choice.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\begin{document}
$\vcenter{\hbox{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-duck}}}}%
\vcenter{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\centering    
        The picture on the left represents \\
        a \textcolor{blue}{graph}. The \textcolor{blue}{source} point is \\
        corresponds to Southampton whereas \\ 
        the \textcolor{blue}{destinations} are the other cities. \newline
        The edges are also labeled with the shortest path between the cities.
\end{minipage} }$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally I would use a `tcolorbox` because then you will most likely have a tool that can be used to address all layout wishes.